# SPFolder.MoveTo is preserving the metadata for the sub-folders while reset the metadata for the root folder

Tags: 2013, development, folder, ssom, move

I have the following console application, which moved some folders from one document library to another within the same SP 2013 site collection:-

```
 SPList sourceomslist = omsWeb.Lists.TryGetList("Order Management");
                        ;
   foreach (SPListItem currentItem in sourceomslist.Items)
          {

            if (currentItem["Status"].ToString() == "Closed")
                {

                             if (currentItem.ContentType.Name.ToLower().Contains("project"))
                       {
                         Console.WriteLine(currentItem["ID"]);
                         SPFolder folder = omsWeb.GetFolder(omsWeb.ServerRelativeUrl + "/Shared Documents/"+currentItem["ID"].ToString() );
                         folder.MoveTo(omsWeb.ServerRelativeUrl + "/ArchDocs/"+currentItem["ID"].ToString() );

                       }
               }

         }
```

now the MoveTo will preserve the metadata for the sub-folders and files, but it will reset the metadata for the roots folders that are been moved. 
So can anyone advice if i can force the MoveTo method to preserve the metadata data for the root folders that are been moved?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need update folder metadata for the root folders after run the MoveTo method, modify the code as below.

```
if (currentItem.ContentType.Name.ToLower().Contains("project"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(currentItem["ID"]);
    SPFolder folder = omsWeb.GetFolder(omsWeb.ServerRelativeUrl + "/Shared Documents/"+currentItem["ID"].ToString());
    var modified = folder.Item["Modified"];
    var created = folder.Item["Created"];    
    folder.MoveTo(omsWeb.ServerRelativeUrl + "/ArchDocs/" + currentItem["ID"].ToString());
    SPFolder tfolder = omsWeb.GetFolder(omsWeb.ServerRelativeUrl + "/ArchDocs/" + currentItem["ID"].ToString());
    tfolder.Item["Created"] = created;
    tfolder.Item["Modified"] = modified;
    tfolder.Item.UpdateOverwriteVersion();
}
```